# What are the blue tickets in CATS?

Tags: cats-crash-arena-turbo-stars

When you press the down arrow to go to ultimate garage, there are blue tickets in the corner of the screen replacing coins, what are these and what are they used for?

Comment: CATS set up you the bomb.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Sorry, I don't understand, can you clarify please?